# Why does this javaScript code create an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

```
let i = 500;
do {
    if (isPrime(i) === false) {
        continue;
    } else {
        para.textContent += i + ', ';
    }
    i--;
} while (i >= 2);
```

and it works well if I moved the (i--) to the start of the loop.

Comment: Because `isPrime(500)` is false. PS no need to test `x === false`, just use `!x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop keeps iterating at  -

```
if (isPrime(i) === false) {  //this condition will be true and code keeps looping because you never increment i
    continue;
}
```

But, in your code where you declare `i--` at the beginning, `i` will keep decreasing no matter what. So the first one will run succesfully as expected, while in the second program, the execution will never go beyond the first `if()` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Initially i=500 , enter loop

```
if (isPrime(i) === false) {
        continue;
    }
```

this condition satisfies, and go to next iteration i value is 500 forever